# How to move Search Service to another server SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

I have multi server farm environment and I have configured my search service
in server where my SharePoint server web applications are running,

my server architecture:
[image]

How can I run the search service in another server?
The server I want to move search service to name is MAX01

When I run the below command:

```
$hostA = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Identity "MAX01"
```

it gives this error:

> The SearchServiceInstance is not found on server "MAX01"

Comment: Pls reconfirm the server name. The server name should be "MAX01", not "MAX01.com". Remove the ".com" postfix and try again.

Comment: Yes I miss spelled it here, I wrote the name correctly when running command, but the above error I mentioned

Comment: After modifying the servername, is it working now? If not then close your management shell and reopen the run the command again.

Comment: Yes the same error

Answer (score 3):

To move the Search Components of SharePoint 2013 to another server can be done via PowerShell. There is no way to move the Search via Central Administration or modifying the Search Topology.

It would be too long to post entire set of steps and commands here in the answer. Therefore I refer you two articles that would help you to move the Search to another server.

[Move a Search Component in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj862354.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Search_Comp_Move)

[Move Search Components To Different Server in SharePoint 2013](https://altfo.wordpress.com/2013/04/19/move-search-components-to-different-server-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Before you move your search to another server, ensure you have planned your Search Architecture as per the best recommendation. Search is a service in SharePoint that needs most of the system resources or else your search components would not run upto the mark.

[Plan enterprise search architecture in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn342836.aspx)

Comment: Take content db of search service application in your source server using SSMS or PowerShell and restore these DBs on your target server.

Comment: These links did not work, do you have another detailed solution